# Write script to create records in table to maintain time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need table which should track the time periods based on year and quarters. When a new year and quarter value is given then current record should be end dated with time period and quarter so that there is no gap between records.

For example: 
Table has `StartYear,StartPeriod, EndYear, EndPeriod` columns.

When input `@NewStartYear, @NewPeriod` are given are as input.

Initial Table Rows:

```
 StartYear  StartPeriod EndYear EndPeriod
 2020/01/01  Q1          NULL     NULL
```

When `@NewStartYear =  2021/01/01 AND @NewPeriod = Q1`

```
 StartYear  StartPeriod  EndYear     EndPeriod
 2020/01/01  Q1          2020/01/01  Q4        -- END DATE CURRENT RECORD WITH Q4 SO THAT NO GAPS
 2021/01/01  Q1          NULL       NULL       -- NEW RECORD WITH NEW START DATE AND QUARTER
```

Next, When `@NewStartYear =  2023/01/01 AND @NewPeriod = Q3`

```
 StartYear  StartPeriod  EndYear          EndPeriod
 2020/01/01  Q1          2020/01/01       Q4 
 2021/01/01  Q1          2023/01/01       Q2    -- END DATE CURRENT RECORD WITH YEAR = 2023 AND Q2 SO THAT NO GAPS
 2023/01/01  Q3          NULL             NULL  -- NEW RECORD WITH NEW START DATE AND QUARTER
```

Please can anyone help me create query to work as per given example above. I am finding it difficult to implement.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried using [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)